# How to Hide Refund button on woocommerce order admin with custom user role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, code-snippets, hook-woocommerce

Is there a way to hide the "Refund" button to all user role, except Admin and Refund Manager...by the way I created the refund manager user role with this plugin [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).

Shop Manager will not see the refund button on woocommerce back-end also...

I hope there is hook/snippets to that button...

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: Any news about my post right here...help please...

Answer (score 0):

```php
function hide_wc_refund_button() {

    global $post;

    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !current_user_can('editor')) {
        return;
    }
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'post.php?post=') === false) {
        return;
    }

    if (empty($post) || $post->post_type != 'shop_order') {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <script>
      jQuery(function () {
            jQuery('.refund-items').hide();
            jQuery('.order_actions option[value=send_email_customer_refunded_order]').remove();
            if (jQuery('#original_post_status').val()=='wc-refunded') {
                jQuery('#s2id_order_status').html('Refunded');
            } else {
                jQuery('#order_status option[value=wc-refunded]').remove();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the woocommerce_admin_order_actions hook for achieve this

```
function custom_woocommerce_admin_order_actions($actions, $order) {
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array('shop-manager', $user->roles)) {
        unset($actions['refund']);
    }
    return $actions;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'custom_woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 10, 2);
```